# Can i use guitar(yamaha f310) clip on directly with speakers without using amplifiers

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I have yamaha f310 ....how can i use clip on directly with speakers for stage performance without using amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The signal from the pups is too weak to make the speakers sound. There needs to be an amplifier to plug guitar into, then that in turn connects to the speakers.

Unless they happen to be powered speakers, in which case, the amp is built in, so you can plug the guitar directly into the input, and sound will emanate from the said speaker.

Comment: Most powered speakers go from line level to speaker level, so the asker would likely need a preamp between the pickup and the powered speaker to go from instrument/mic level to line level.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks for that, I forgot they're only containing a power amp and speakers, although I'm sure I've used similar with keyboards without using a pre-amp, at the same sort of levels as a guitar would. Though those may have contained a pre-amp without me realising.

Comment: AFAIK only some electric pianos (e.g., Fender Rhodes as opposed to Wurlitzer 200A) and Clavinets are keyboards that don't have preamps. Not sure about B3s and other organs - probably depends on the exact model. If the clip on pickup is piezo, which I bet it is, it will definitely need a preamp.

Comment: It is now fairly common on powered speakers to have a pre-amp/gain setting that is capable of  taking from mic up to line level directly.  Some are marketed to be used directly as a kind of mini PA.  The EV's I have use two inputs, can take Mic input directly, and I have used one  with an Electric guitar and Mic successfully.

Comment: Guys thanks for your answers .......i didn't knew about powered speakers before this. .....you guys know any good powered speaker in budget ....so that i can use it without amplifier .....i just want that for rehearsing and  stage performances.

Comment: Sudhansu - For small PA uses I use Kustom PA 50's.  Very small & have the inputs needed.  For larger gigs I use these as the monitors.  I've bought for $80-100(US).